# Frontend framework to consume RESTful backend

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, rest, jakarta-ee

I've build a RESTful backend in Spring + Hibernate framework. Now, i'm starting with frontend in Spring MVC. So, my jsp pages make an AJAX call to the frontend URL which inturn calls the backend URL to get the data.

Is this a proper way of implementation? Or should i re-think on the design? How about replacing frontend Spring MVC with Angular.js or any other framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, my jsp pages make an AJAX call to the frontend URL which inturn calls the backend URL to get the data.

No. The JSPs are your frontend. JSPs are one way to generate and deliver HTML to the client. When it is successfully delivered to the client, the HTML is rendered and the JS is executed. 
Within the JS-code you are able to make calls to the backend to get your data.

> Is this a proper way of implementation?

Yes.

> How about replacing frontend Spring MVC with Angular.js or any other framework?

You are free to do that as you like.
Since recommending one or the other framework would be based on my subjective opinion, I won't say anything but: Angular is en vogue. So: yes, it is one possible solution.

And since Angular itself is only a JS-framework you could combine it without further ado with JSPs.

Comment: Yeah sorry for that wrong framing of sentence. Now, my JS makes Ajax calls to frontend Spring controller (in the same app), which inturn calls the backend (which is also Spring MVC). Im just confused about the part where i have used Spring in frontend. Is it ok? Or do i need to allow the Ajax in JS to directly call the backend?

Comment: As I said: the controllers are your backend, which is called from tge frontend. What you perhaps meant is the "frontcontroller" which is also part of tge backend.

Comment: so, if i'm making rest calls from my js-code, wont the rest URLs be exposed at client side? is there any way to protect them, in terms of security?

Comment: Spring security can be used to secure the urls.  http://www.baeldung.com/2011/10/31/securing-a-restful-web-service-with-spring-security-3-1-part-3/

Comment: »so, if i'm making rest calls from my js-code, wont the rest URLs be exposed at client side?« That is the idea behind REST: to make the system accessible via URL to many different clients. And as @user2122031 wrote: Spring Security helps to make them secure